# "Application is agent" doesn't work in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, osx-yosemite

I'm working on a status bar app in Swift. I tried to hide the window by adding `Application is agent (UIElement)` item and set it to `YES`, but it just doesn't work - it always shows the window and the menu bar.

**My storyboard:**

[image]

**Info.plist:**

[image]

What can I do ?

Comment: I have the same issue and I can not fix. You could do it somehow?

Comment: Actually can not fixed this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Configure your NSStatusBar with a title, image, alternate image, etc.. and you'll see it in the system's Status Bar.

```
    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)

    statusItem.button?.title = "LG"
    statusItem.button?.image = NSImage(named: "LGIcon")
    statusItem.button?.alternateImage = NSImage(named: "LGIcon")
```

Answer (score 0):

The option for "Target -> Info -> Curstom macOS Appli.. : Application is agent (UIElement)" only hide the App from **Dock**

To hide the window on SwiftUI you need to change your App Scene:

```
var body: some Scene {
    Settings{
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can change the ApplicationDelegate

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
        window.close()
    }
    ...
 }
```